# Notifying about events from dll to main app

Tags: delphi, dll, callback, message

I am developing application which intend to be cross platform. I used to use Windows Messages but now I am dropping it out. I replaced messages with callbacks but regardless I can use different technologies I am not aware of different possibilites when not using windows messages.

Well I have main exe aplication and some dll plugins. I have some objects and threads in dll and I would like to notify main application about some changes that DLL made to data structure.

As I said I am currently working with some callbacks. To provide compatibility with different languages (C++, VB, C#) I have non-object type of callback. I am not sure if other languages supports callback of object.

So my questions are:

- What are the alternatives (cross-platform) to windows messages? Can callbacks replace messages?
- Do other languages support callback of object?
- I guess other languages have different technologies as alternative to messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my questions are:
>      What are the alternatives (cross-platform) to windows messages? Can callbacks replace messages?

Yes you can replace messages with callbacks.

> Do other languages support callback of object?

You shouldn't use object methods as callbacks. Common practice in portable code is use of handles (notify calling convention):

DLL source:

```
type
  THandle = LongWord;
  {$IF SizeOf(THandle) < SizeOf(Pointer))}
  {$MESSAGE Error 'Invallid handle type'}
  {$ENDIF}

  TCallback = procedure(const aHandle: THandle); cdecl;

  var
      gCallback: record
        Routine: TCallback;
        Obj: TObject;
        Info: string
  end;

  function Object2Handle(const aObj: TObject): THandle;
  begin
    Result:= THandle(Pointer(aObj))
  end;

  function Handle2Object(const aHandle: THandle; out aObj: TObject): Boolean;
  begin
    if gCallback.Obj <> nil then
      if aHandle = Object2Handle(gCallback.Obj) then
      begin
        aObj:= gCallback.Obj;
        Result:= true;
        Exit // WARRNING: program flow disorder
      end;

    aObj:= nil;
    Result:= false
  end;

procedure DoCallback();
begin
  if Assigned(gCallback.Routine) then
    gCallback.Routine(Object2Handle(gCallback.Obj))
end;

procedure SetupCallback(const aCallback: TCallback); cdecl;
begin
  gCallback.Routine:= aCallback;
end;

procedure DoSomething(const aHandle: THandle; out aInfo: string); cdecl;
var
  O: TObject;
begin
  if Handle2Object(aHandle, O) then
    aInfo:= Format('%s class object %s', [O.ClassName(), gCallback.Info])
end;

procedure Test();
begin
  gCallback.Obj:= TStream.Create();
  try
    gCallback.Info:= 'created';
    DoCallback();
  finally
    FreeAndNil(gCallback.Obj)
  end;
  gCallback.Obj:= TMemoryStream.Create();
  try
    gCallback.Info:= 'will be freed';
    DoCallback();
  finally
    FreeAndNil(gCallback.Obj)
  end
end;

exports
  SetupCallback,
  DoSomething,
  Test;
```

Executable source:

```
procedure Cb(const aHandle: THandle); cdecl;
const
  STUPID: THandle = 1;
  EQUALLY_STUPID = $DEAD;
var
  S: string;
begin
  DoSomething(STUPID, S);
  DoSomething(aHandle, S);
  DoSomething(EQUALLY_STUPID, S)
end;

begin
  SetupCallback(@Cb);
  Test()
end.
```

Edited: You can't shoot yourself in you leg now.

> I guess other languages have different technologies as alternative to messages?

OS have a few message alternatives. However not many truly portable.

You can also use:

- sockets,
- (IMO too big in this case?) ready messaging system (my favorite [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org))

Comment: If the DLL knows the type of the thing the EXE is going to store in the handle parameter, and then the DLL even *uses* the handle parameter as that type, then you've missed the point of handles. The module providing the handle should be allowed to store *any* data type in it, without fear of the consumers of the handle using it in any way except to pass it back to the handle provider. In your example, the EXE must store a valid TObject reference. If it doesn't, then DoSomething will crash. May as well just pass TObject directly instead of this THandle charade.

Comment: And passing TObject reference "provide compatibility with different languages" and portability?!? I was just show simplest possible handles implementation, nothing more.

Comment: Well my problem is very simple. I don't need to pass objects I just need to notify main app about some changes so I can refresh GUI. I am looking for solution that is cross platform and can be used with other languages. I guess I will do it with callbacks. I just needed some approvals and different aspects to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly use callback functions instead of messages. You can't use callback *methods* because only Delphi and C++ Builder understand how to invoke Delphi method pointers. However, you can use callback *objects* with any language that supports COM. Here's an example for a plug-in to notify the application that the data structure has changed:

1. Define an interface.

   ```
   type
     IDataStructureChanged = interface
       ['{GUID}']
       procedure Call; stdcall;
     end;
   ```

   You could add some parameters to the method so the plug-in can tell *how* the data structure changed, or pass some value indicating which plug-in is making the notification.
2. Implement it in the application.

   ```
   type
     TDataStructureChangedListener = class(TInterfacedObject, IDataStructureChanged)
     private
       FForm: TForm;
       procedure Call; stdcall;
     public
       constructor Create(Form: TForm);
     end;
   ```

   When you instantiate that class, you can pass it a reference to your program's main form, or whatever other information your program will need to be able to take action when a plug-in eventually calls the `Call` method. Implement `Call` to make your application do whatever it needs to do when a data structure changes.
3. Pass a reference to each of the plug-ins when you initialize them.

   ```
   ChangeListener := TDataStructureChangedListener.Create(Self);
   for i := 0 to Pred(PlugIns.Count) do
     PlugIns[i].Init(ChangeListener);
   ```

   The plug-in should store a reference to the listener object, and when the data structure changes, it can call the `Call` method to notify your application.

What I've described here is what's generally known as an *event sink*. You can have more than one in your program. If there are multiple events to handle, you could have a separate interface for each kind of event, or you could group them all into a single interface and have a different method for each event. You could have a different sink object for each plug-in, or you could give each plug-in a reference to the same sink object, and then pass a plug-in-ID parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I would definately use callbacks.  The main app could give a callback function to the DLL to call when needed, and then the callback function itself can send window messages to the app if it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Remy, (!).  A straightforward callback allows the handler to implement any kind of further communication it chooses - it might post a message, it may push a parameter onto a queue, whatever it wants.  If you want to be cross-platform, you are going to have to resort to passing in, and out, simple types.  It's usual to pass in a 'user context' pointer when callbacks are set up.  The callback passes this pointer into the handler.  This allows callers to pass in a context object as a pointer/int and to recover it in the handler, (by casting the pointer/int back to an object).  The handler can then call methods on the context, no matter whether it's Delphi, C++ etc.